# Update value in array in Mongodb using Meteor gives error 403

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I hope you can help me with this problem of mine. Please forgive me if I'm not expressing correctly what I want.

I have a Mongodb collection with arrays holding objects and I need to change the value of one of these objects variables. I found the correct answer to do it in Mongodb but when using it in Meteor it will complain about only being able to update by `_id`

My collection is something like this

```
{
  _id: 'akjsdakudsh',
  subs: [
    {
      name: 'name1',
      seen: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'name2',
      seen: false,
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 'ako0iqwjeqasdf',
  subs: [
    {
      name: 'name1',
      seen: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'Fantastic',
      seen: true,
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore if I want to change `seen` to `true` for the one called `name2` I do in Mongodb

```
db.coll.update(
    {
        _id : 'akjsdakudsh',
        'subs.name': 'name2'
    },
    {
        $set: { 'subs.$.seen': true }
    }
  );
```

And this works like a charm. The problem comes when trying to do it in Meteor because it will throw an error `403` `Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID`.

I understand what the problem is but I don't have an `_id` for the array's elements, and I don't need it for anything else.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong or some neat workaround to solve my problem? Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just call a meteor method that does the job of inser/update/delete for you? Worth looking into [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3775)

Comment: Thank you @blueren, that was actually the way to do it. I'm still trying to understand how things work in Meteor.